# Cannot seem to understand Magento email sending logic

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.9

Can someone please explain how Magento(1.9.0) email sending works. I can't seem to find where the file for sending email from a contact form is. I see that the action attribute of the form points to "contacts/index/post/" but I can't seem to trace it.

Also cannot find the mail log or the which module or service magento uses to send the email itself.

I am trying to use external smtp server for multisite Magento and I need to do some custom logic and not some extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to app\code\core\Mage\Contacts location to see all the logic of contact.
It is used to send email or anything related to contact.

Also, if we want to change any contact settings then go to system> configuration> contacts(under general tab).

Let me know if anything else you need to know.

Cheers!!